# Apache Zeppelin conditional branching (IF/ELSE)?

Tags: python, impala, apache-zeppelin

How do you achieve conditional branching in Zeppelin?

e.g.

```
IF <condition> THEN <run paragraph A> ELSE <run paragraph B>
```

or for Impala queries in a Zeppelin notebook,

```
IF <condition> THEN <run Impala query A> ELSE <run Impala query B>
```

Do I need to somehow use Python or Spark?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `z.run` to run a specific paragraph :

```scala
if (condition == "condition1") z.run("paragraph_id1") else z.run("paragraph_id2")
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: great thanks. I thought all the paragraphs in a note one after the other anyway though, so presumably there needs to be way to stop this from happening so the choice can be made? Also, is your solution also possible in Python or just Spark? Thanks